# Decode a single hevc iframe in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hevc

I am running a hevc encoder with every frame as an iframe and writing each frame out of the encoder to a separate file. I want to decode a single frame to a png. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. In case the encoded frame is raw H.265 without container, and the file extension is `.265` or `.h265` or `.hevc`, use `ffmpeg -i input.265 output.png`. In case the file has other extension use: `ffmpeg -f hevc -i input.abc 1.png`. There may be some cases when it's not going to work. In case it's not working, please post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Have to make sure every frame has sps and pps and it will work with `ffmpeg -f hevc -i file out.png`